# Print list-matrix combination

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am trying to print a combination of np.array values, a string and and some values I get from an iterator.

The code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

site = np.genfromtxt('.....\Plot_1.txt', dtype=None, delimiter='\t')
c1 = np.array([148, 108])
c2 = np.array([181, 147])
c3 = np.array([173, 153])
c4 = np.array([98, 221])
c5 = np.array([43, 153])

trees_list = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]

def trees_pixel(rc_list, matrix):
        t_row = rc_list[0]
        t_col = rc_list[1]
        tree = matrix[t_row, t_col]
        for i in range(1, 6, 1):
            print "C",i,"=",tree
        return tree

for i in trees_list:
        trees_pixel(i, site)
```

Site is a np.array of 400x370 row/columns, that I need to read the values from. C1...C5 are the locations (row/column) from the 'site' array.

My code prints the following:

```
C 1 = 8.266602
C 2 = 8.266602
C 3 = 8.266602
C 4 = 8.266602
C 5 = 8.266602
C 1 = 17.89282
C 2 = 17.89282
C 3 = 17.89282
C 4 = 17.89282
C 5 = 17.89282
C 1 = 18.31433
C 2 = 18.31433
C 3 = 18.31433
C 4 = 18.31433
C 5 = 18.31433
etc...
```

But what I expected was:

```
C 1 = 8.266602
C 2 = 17.89282
C 3 = 18.31433
C 4 = 20.47229
C 5 = 13.5907
```

How can I do this, so I will avoid the repeating pattern? Thanks!

Comment: there's only one loop, why is `C 1` repeated?

Comment: I put all the code now, sorry, forgot some lines.

Comment: Still, `t_row` and `t_col` appear to not be advancing through the matrix, they're just looking at `c1` and `c2`. I don't understand how your output number changes; are you not missing a `for` at the start of `trees_pixel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating twice, once inside trees_pixel and once outside of it. If I understand what you mean, you want something that looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np

site = np.random.random((400, 370)) # Used in place of your data
c1 = np.array([148, 108])
c2 = np.array([181, 147])
c3 = np.array([173, 153])
c4 = np.array([98, 221])
c5 = np.array([43, 153])

trees_list = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]

def trees_pixel(rc_list, listIdx, matrix):
        t_row = rc_list[0]
        t_col = rc_list[1]
        tree = matrix[t_row, t_col]
        print "C",listIdx,"=",tree
        return tree

for i in xrange(len(trees_list)):
    trees_pixel(trees_list[i], i+1, site)


C 1 = 0.820317259854
C 2 = 0.960883528796
C 3 = 0.363985436225
C 4 = 0.189575015844
C 5 = 0.667578060856
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks! :)